# Conversion ms sql function into mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm facing a problem while converting ms sql function into mysql. Here is ms sql function code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [crewu2].[isAvailable] (@OwnerID int, @DateFrom Smalldatetime, @DateTo Smalldatetime)  
RETURNS bit AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @t bit  
    IF @DateFrom IS NULL or @DateTo IS NULL 
        or EXISTS (select DateID
                     from [client_BlackDates]
                    where OwnerID=@OwnerID 
                      and ((DateFrom<=@DateFrom and @DateFrom<=DateTo) 
                            or (DateFrom<=@DateTo and @DateTo<=DateTo)))  
        SET @t=0  
    ELSE  
        SET @t=1  
RETURN @t  
END
```

And here is converted in mysql:

```
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE FUNCTION isAvailable (OwnerID INT, DateFrom DATETIME, DateTo DATETIME)  
RETURNS BIT   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE t BIT;  
    IF DateFrom IS NULL OR DateTo IS NULL
        OR EXISTS (SELECT DateID
                     FROM client_BlackDates
                    WHERE OwnerID=OwnerID 
                      AND ((DateFrom<=DateFrom AND DateFrom<=DateTo)
                            OR (DateFrom<=DateTo AND DateTo<=DateTo)))  
        SET t=0;  
    ELSE  
        SET t=1;  
    RETURN t  
END $$  
DELIMITER;
```

but it gives me following error:

`Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET t=0;
ELSE
SET t=1;
RETURN t
END' at line 6`

Please anyone help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work(You have missed `THEN` and `END IF`):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION isAvailable (OwnerID INT, DateFrom DATETIME, DateTo DATETIME)
RETURNS BIT
BEGIN
DECLARE t BIT;
IF DateFrom IS NULL OR DateTo IS NULL OR EXISTS (SELECT DateID FROM client_BlackDates WHERE OwnerID=OwnerID AND ((DateFrom<=DateFrom AND DateFrom<=DateTo) OR (DateFrom<=DateTo AND DateTo<=DateTo)))
**THEN** 
SET t=0;
ELSE
SET t=1;    
RETURN t;
**END IF;**
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Refer MySQL [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if-statement.html).

Comment: one more function can i ask??

Comment: here is my second function please take a look on it..
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791055/conversion-microsoft-sql-to-mysql]

Comment: it gives me this error:
`Error Code : 1415  
Not allowed to return a result set from a function
`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into MySQL manual to the [IF..THEN..ELSE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html) sintax

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION isAvailable (OwnerID INT, DateFrom DATETIME, DateTo DATETIME)  
RETURNS BIT   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE t BIT;  
    IF DateFrom IS NULL OR DateTo IS NULL 
       OR EXISTS (SELECT DateID
                    FROM client_BlackDates
                   WHERE OwnerID=OwnerID
                      AND ((DateFrom<=DateFrom AND DateFrom<=DateTo)
                            OR (DateFrom<=DateTo AND DateTo<=DateTo)))
        THEN
        SET t = 0;
    ELSE  
        SET t = 1;  
    END IF;
    RETURN t;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```