# conversion microsoft sql to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm converting this into mysql from mssql but it is giving me this error:

**Error Code : 1415 Not allowed to return a result set from a function**

What am I doing wrong?

```
DELIMITER $$  

CREATE    FUNCTION GetPositionList (orderDetID NUMERIC)  
RETURNS NVARCHAR(200)    
DETERMINISTIC   
BEGIN   
DECLARE strToReturn NVARCHAR(50);  
DECLARE strPos NVARCHAR(50);  
DECLARE strPosOtherRes NVARCHAR(50);  
DECLARE strTPos NVARCHAR(50);  
DECLARE strTPosOtherResr NVARCHAR(50)


SET strToReturn = '';  
SET strPos = SELECT `POSITION` FROM orderdetails WHERE OrderID = orderDetID;
SET strPosOtherRes = SELECT SecPosition FROM orderdetails WHERE OrderID = orderDetID;
SET strTPos = SELECT TeamPosition FROM orderdetails WHERE OrderID = orderDetID;
SET strTPosOtherResr = SELECT TeamSecPosition FROM orderdetails WHERE OrderID = orderDetID;


IF(strPos != '') THEN SET strToReturn = CONCAT(strPos , ',');
END IF;
IF(strPosOtherRes != '' ) THEN SET strToReturn = CONCAT(strToReturn ,  strPosOtherRes , ',');
END IF;
IF(strTPos != '' ) THEN SET strToReturn =  CONCAT(strToReturn ,  strTPos , ',');
END IF;
IF(strTPosOtherResr != '' ) THEN SET strToReturn =  CONCAT(strToReturn , strTPosOtherResr , ',');
END IF;     
RETURN SUBSTRING( strToReturn, 0, LENGTH(strToReturn) );  
END $$  
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't an universal converter. Please read FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: I'm converting this into mysql from mssql but it is giving me this error: `Error Code : 1415 Not allowed to return a result set from a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for selecting values into variables in MySQL is [`select ... into`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html). For example you could write:

```
SELECT POSITION, SecPosition FROM orderdetails 
WHERE OrderID = orderDetID INTO strPos, strPosOtherRes;
```

The message "Not allowed to return a result set from a function" means that the select statements as they stand now would be returning a resultset from the function, and functions can only return single values.

Comment: sorry dear, now it is giving syntax error... :(

Comment: Update your question with your new program and error message, or ask a new question. If the syntax error comes from SELECT ... INTO you can refer to this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html

Comment: updated question. kindly check now.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after the last DECLARE.

Comment: nothing happened with semicolon. Same result as syntax error..
    syntax to use near 'SELECT `POSITION` FROM orderdetails WHERE     OrderID = orderDetID; SET strPosOther' at line 12

Comment: That's a different syntax error. Use `select .. into` like I said in the answer, or change each `set x = select...` to `set x = (select..)`

Comment: one more function can i ask having same issue? can i paste here in this comment box??